# Python - XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I got following [xml code](http://dpaste.com/816679/).
How to get "comment" from that xml using minidom.parse function?
I can get "user:" and cell value, but can't with "comment".

Comment: Your `dpaste.com` link is no longer available. Try to copy related XML schema to here or your question will become meaningless for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your xml code is saved to "test.xml":

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

dom1 = parse("test.xml")

for node in dom1.getElementsByTagName('t'):
    print node.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

This should print the inner values of all tags "".